# GreenDao- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table TAREAS has no column named

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao

I am trying to the insert a data en my table Tareas. I , m using a ORM (GreenDao).But when run my app, the log cat show that no exist a table named Tareas. I dont understand this because when I have created my database, the Tareas Table has a column named Tipo.

> 03-30 07:51:32.758 29389-29389/tipiwiny.greendao E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: tipiwiny.greendao, PID: 29389                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table TAREAS has no column
>
> named TIPO (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TAREAS
>   ('_id','DURACION','TIPO','DESCRIPCION','USUARIO','REALIZADA') VALUES
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:994)
>                                                                              at
>   de.greenrobot.dao.internal.TableStatements.getInsertStatement(TableStatements.java:48)
>                                                                              at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insert(AbstractDao.java:293)
>                                                                              at tipiwiny.greendao.CrearTarea.añadirTarea(CrearTarea.java:60)
>                                                                              at tipiwiny.greendao.CrearTarea.access$000(CrearTarea.java:18)
>                                                                              at tipiwiny.greendao.CrearTarea$1.onClick(CrearTarea.java:42)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                              atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

My database is defined how:

```
 private static void createDatabase(Schema schema) {
    Entity usuario = schema.addEntity("Usuario");
    usuario.addIdProperty();
    usuario.addStringProperty("nombre").notNull();
    usuario.addStringProperty("apellidos").notNull();
    usuario.addStringProperty("password").notNull();
    usuario.addStringProperty("roll").notNull();

    Entity habilidad = schema.addEntity("Habilidad");
    habilidad.addIdProperty();
    Property usuarioIdProperty = habilidad.addLongProperty("usuarioId").notNull().getProperty();
    habilidad.addToOne(usuario, usuarioIdProperty);
    habilidad.addIntProperty("tipo").notNull();

    Entity tarea=schema.addEntity("Tareas");
    tarea.addIdProperty();

    tarea.addIntProperty("duracion").notNull();
    tarea.addIntProperty("tipo").notNull();
    tarea.addStringProperty("descripcion").notNull();
    tarea.addStringProperty("usuario");
    tarea.addBooleanProperty("realizada");


}
```

When you execute this code to generate the tables, the class TareasDao is created and the method createTable is:

```
  /** Creates the underlying database table. */
public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
    String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'TAREAS' (" + //
            "'_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + // 0: id
            "'DURACION' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 1: duracion
            "'TIPO' INTEGER NOT NULL ," + // 2: tipo
            "'DESCRIPCION' TEXT NOT NULL ," + // 3: descripcion
            "'USUARIO' TEXT," + // 4: usuario
            "'REALIZADA' INTEGER);"); // 5: realizada
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

**Details :**

One possible reason could be that you created the table first, ran the migration and then added fields later.

So there could be two possible solutions :-

**1 :** Remove the app from your phone (uninstall) and it will remove all the tables with it. And then reinstalling will re-create all the tables.

**2 :** Change your `onUpdate` method in DaoMaster  to drop all the tables and recreating them.

```
/** WARNING: Drops all table on Upgrade! Use only during development. */
public static class DevOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {
    public DevOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, name, factory);
        Log.i("greenDAO", "DevOpenHelper: constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
        //Remember to remove this line before moving to production.
       dropAllTables(db,true); 
       onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: Thanks! I resolved my problem. I removed the app from my phone and after I remove the database from Android Device Monitor. Finally, I returned to generate the database

Comment: Please share your solution! How you did that?

Comment: Good job! It was more or less about removing previous database and creating the new one. Great we did it. :)